# Two functions I want to implement in my WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

1) I want to create an image slider like here: https://rosaliedemo.wordpress.com/ (I'm using the same Wordpress Theme). There is no widget available to achieve that. Notice that those pictures are linked to a specific post I made. Is that a popular widget or plugin I need to implement somehow?

2) Secondly I want that the latest posts are seperated in 2 colums which already works. But I want that the *first* latest post is only one column.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is quite an open-ended question. Might be better to separate these out into two separate questions, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. That Slide Images is a Plugin, here you can find it: http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/flexslider
2. I really don't understand at all your question, you want to divide a post in columns? I use to used this plugin to make columns inside posts:
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/column-posts/

Let me know if it helps.